# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library mcrypt

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, mcrypt

I'm trying to build an app written in PHP (Laravel) from other devs, using Composer (I'm new to both).

I've installed mcrypt for PHP v5.5 with Homebrew (OSX 10.11) but every time I update my dependencies with "./composer.phar update" it returns me this error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.33/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mcrypt.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.33/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mcrypt.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: I have had a couple of these. A restart usually does it for me.

Comment: @Chris thanks but it doesn't worked for me

Comment: Did you check if the file mcrypt.so exists? And is readable by the account used to to run the proces?

Comment: @CharlieVieillard yes, it exists but it's not in the same path.
This is the current mcrypt.so path "/usr/local/Cellar/php55-mcrypt/5.5.33/"

Comment: Hmm that doesn't smell good. What kind of operating system are you using? And what kind of webserver?

Comment: OSX 10.11 and Apache 2 with MAMP. It's not my cup of tea :).

Comment: The modules (so files) should be configured in the php configuration file (php.ini). In that file there should be a configuration parameter **extension_dir = /path/to/so/files/**. More information under the chapter **Enabling mcrypt.so  php Extension** at https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-for-php-on-mac-osx-10-10-yosemite-for-a-development-server/.